# Golang unexpected behaviour while implementing concurrency using channel and select statement

Tags: go, concurrency, publish-subscribe, goroutine

Below is my implementation of the Pub/Sub model in golang using concurrency. The code executes as expected sometimes but sometimes it gives output like this:

**Output**

```
message received on channel 2: Hello World
message received on channel 3: Hello World
message received on channel 1: Hello World
message received on channel 1: 
subscriber 1's context cancelled
message received on channel 3: Only channels 2 and 3 should print this
message received on channel 2: Only channels 2 and 3 should print this
```

Key thing to note here is that subscriber 1 printed `message received on channel 1:`   even after there is a call in the main function to remove it as a subscriber. Subscriber 1 should only receive one message. What seems to be happening is that subscriber receives a message from `subscriber.out` before the `dctx` is cancelled. How can I fix this. The subscriber's goroutine is launched in the `AddSubscriber` method.

**Expected execution:**
Channel 1 should only print once and then it's context should be cancelled and it's goroutine should exit.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
  var err error
  
    publisher := NewPublisher()

  publisher.AddSubscriber()
  publisher.AddSubscriber()
  publisher.AddSubscriber()

  publisher.Start()
  
  err = publisher.Publish("Hello World")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("could not publish: %v\n", err)
  }

  err = publisher.RemoveSubscriber(1)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("could not remove subscriber: %v\n", err)
  }
  
  err = publisher.Publish("Only channels 2 and 3 should print this")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("could not publish: %v\n", err)
  }

  // this is merely to keep the server running
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**publisher.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

// Publisher sends messages received in its in channel
// to all the Subscribers listening to it.
type Publisher struct {
    sequence    uint
    in          chan string
    subscribers map[uint]*Subscriber
    sync.RWMutex
    ctx         context.Context
    cancel      *context.CancelFunc
}

// NewPublisher returns a new Publisher with zero subscribers.
// A Publishers needs to be started with the Publisher.Start()
// method before it can start publishing incoming messages.
func NewPublisher() *Publisher {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    return &Publisher{subscribers: map[uint]*Subscriber{}, ctx: ctx, cancel: &cancel}
}

// AddSubscriber creates a new Subscriber that starts
// listening to the messages sent by this Publisher.
func (p *Publisher) AddSubscriber() {
    dctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(p.ctx)
    p.Lock()
    nextId := p.sequence + 1
    subscriber := NewSubscriber(nextId, dctx, &cancel)
    p.subscribers[nextId] = subscriber
    p.sequence = p.sequence + 1
    p.Unlock()

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-p.ctx.Done():
                fmt.Printf("parent context cancelled\n")
                (*subscriber.cancel)()
                return
            case <-dctx.Done():
                fmt.Printf("subscriber %d's context cancelled\n", subscriber.id)
                return
            case msg := <-subscriber.out:
                fmt.Printf("message received on channel %d: %s\n", subscriber.id, msg)
            }
        }
    }()  
}

// Publish sends the msg to all the subscribers subscribed to it.
func (p *Publisher) Publish(msg string) error {
    // publish only if Publisher has been started
    if p.in == nil {
        return errors.New("publisher not started yet")
    }
    // publish only if subscriber count > 0
    p.RLock()
    if len(p.subscribers) == 0 {
        return errors.New("no subscribers to receive the message")
    }
    p.RUnlock()

    // send message to in channel
    // establish lock to ensure no modifications take place
    // while the message is being sent
    p.Lock()
    p.in <- msg
    p.Unlock()

    return nil
}

// Start initializes the the publishers in channel
// and makes it ready to start publishing incoming messages.
func (p *Publisher) Start() {
    in := make(chan string)
    p.in = in

    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-p.ctx.Done():
                // using break here only breaks out of select statement
                // instead of breaking out of the loop
                fmt.Printf("done called on publisher\n")
                return
            case msg := <-p.in:
                p.RLock()
                for _, subscriber := range p.subscribers {
                    subscriber.out <- msg
                }
                p.RUnlock()
            }
        }
    }()
}

// Stop prevents the Publisher from listening to any
// incoming messages by closing the in channel.
func (p *Publisher) Stop() {
    // should I also remove all subscribers to prevent it from panicking?
    (*p.cancel)()
}

// RemoveSubscriber removes the subscriber specified by the given id.
// It returns an error "could not find subscriber"
// if Subscriber with the given id is not subscribed to the Publisher.
func (p *Publisher) RemoveSubscriber(id uint) error {
    p.Lock()
    defer p.Unlock()
    subscriber, ok := p.subscribers[id]

    if !ok {
        return errors.New("could not find subscriber")
    }

    (*subscriber.cancel)()
    delete(p.subscribers, id)
    close(subscriber.out)

    return nil
}
```

Comment: here's a minimal reproducible example for you: https://go.dev/play/p/by-926DN-V_h. As you can see, the effect of calling `context.CancelFunc` and `close(chan)` does not have to keep the order.

Comment: here's another example without `context.CancelFunc`, just 2 channels (`context.WithCancel` uses channel under the hood): https://go.dev/play/p/TQSQccjjeCg

Comment: Use the [two-value form of the receive operator](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/4): `case msg, ok := <-subscriber.out`. If ok is false, return. Unless you need dctx for something else, get rid of it. Otherwise you have two termination signals that may disagree.